# efficent way of manuplating json file by using xpath?

Tags: java, json, file, xpath, jackson

```
{
"session":
{
    "name":"lkihilh",
    "value":"yjgiygugg"
},
"loginInfo":
{
    "loginCount":78,
    "previousLoginTime":"2014-12-02T11:12:40.256+0530"
}
```

}

this is a Json file which I am Manipulating by XPath by following  code

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Object jsonObj=mapper.readValue(new File(json file), Object.class);


        PropertyUtils.setProperty(jsonObj, "session.value", "new value");
        PropertyUtils.setProperty(jsonObj, "session.name", "new name");
        mapper.writeValue(new File(json file),jsonObj);
```

At the last line of code `mapper.writevalue`is rewriting the entire file.

This is ok for small json file but if the file is large it will take up a lot of resources so is there a more effecient way to do it?

Comment: @flup so I have created the new question

Answer (score 1):

There is a JsonPath lib, JsonPath expressions always refer to a JSON structure in the same way as XPath expression are used in combination with an XML document

please see this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: i know about the json path library bit my question how to manipulate the json file efficiently without rewriting the whole file

Comment: What makes you think that XPath would help?

Comment: If you dont want to write the whole file, you cant use jsonPath or jackson, you can use java RandomAccessFile to read and write the file,